# Function passes undefined to called function in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-apps-script

I am new in Google Apps Script and some features seems to really hard to get in my understanding. In my code: (look carefully to script element near the end of the body)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
//some code ... 
    </style></head>
  <body>
  <div><h1>Cabeçalho escolar</h1></div>
  <div class="palco">
    <img id="dataShow"/>
 </div>
 
  <script>
    function whenReady(dataImage) //shows the content png image 
    {
       document.getElementById("dataShow").scr = "image/png;base64;"+dataImage; //I dont know if this will work; dataImage should be a base64Encode output from a blob png (that was zipped together with others files) 
//the second parameter is a index to pick up the png file.
    }
       google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(whenReady).getFromZippedData("example.zip",0) 
    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The `getFromZippedData` function should pass its return value to `whenReady` function. But, to do this, it calls another function (`getPic`), passing its first parameter to such function. See bellow:

```
function getPic(fileName) {

var pasta = 'DirectoryName'; 
var arquivos = DriveApp.getRootFolder().getFoldersByName(pasta).next().getFiles(); // yes, the first match... for while, assume that exists such folder
  while( arquivos.hasNext() )
  {
    var candidato = arquivos.next();
    if( candidato.getName() === fileName )
    {
      return Utilities.unzip( candidato.getBlob() );
    }
  }
  Logger.log("Erro ao procurar o arquivo \""+fileName+"\" na função getPic") // aula 
  return null;
}

function getFromZippedData( picFile , num )
{

  var slides = getPic( picFile ); // <-- THIS IS THE POINT (main)
   if( 0 < num )
     num = 0;
   if( num >= slides.length )
     num = slides.length - 1;
   return Utilities.base64Encode( slides[num] );
}
```

**Problem**

No parameter is passed from `getFromZippedFile` to `getPic` (`Logger` accuses `undefined` parameter to `picFile`).

**Questions?**

How do I pass parameters from function to "google-side" function properly? The paramters used are primitive javascript types, as pointed in Google Apps Script reference. Is it needed even to "google-side" function?

**Side-Question (if doesn't imply 'duplicate')**

How do I display the content of the unzipped Blob (that is a png image) in a HTML document?

> Sorry if I have made a stupid question, but I have spend unproductive hours on this. This minimal code was revised, but something could be wrong. I am really tired right now. It's possible some mistakes getting place. Ignore them (if possible) and advise me about them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your question as follows.

1. You want to know the reason of the issue of `No parameter is pass from getFromZippedFile to getPic (Logger accuses undefined paramter to picFile.)`.
2. You want to put the unzipped PNG image on HTML side.

For this, how about this answer?

### Answer 1:

I think that the reason of your issue is that `slides[num]` of `Utilities.base64Encode( slides[num] );` is `Blob`. In this case, please use the byte array. So please modify your script as follows.

#### From:

```
return Utilities.base64Encode( slides[num] );
```

#### To:

```
return Utilities.base64Encode(slides[num].getBytes());
```

- In this case, from your script, it supposes that `slides[num]` is the blob.

### Answer 2:

I think that there is a modification point for putting the base64 encoded image in your HTML side. Please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
document.getElementById("dataShow").scr = "image/png;base64;"+dataImage;
```

#### To:

```
document.getElementById("dataShow").src = "data:image/png;base64,"+dataImage;
```

### References:

- [base64Encode(data)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#base64encodedata)
- [The Image Embed element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img)
- [Data URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs)

Comment: I realize these five minutes ago! Or less! Any away! Thank you too much!

I have found problems in image display... I will keep trying!

Bye bye!

Comment: Detail: I was visting/coming here to change the script related to second question. 

The first question was resolved by, simply, changing all variable names and doing the change you suggest. ( I've noticed that the naming in the minimal script was better than the original ones! LoL); In fact, It wasn't clear what was the problem (not passing the parameters to called function. perhaps a error implies in another... no idea).

Comment: @Daniel Bandeira Thank you for your additional information.